# Shmuel Yosef Agnon's Nobel Prize Speech Audio?

Tags: history, midrash, speeches-addresses

Does anyone know where I can find a recording of Shmuel Yosef Agnon's speech for winning the Nobel Prize?

Comment: Speaking of "midrash", can someone merge "drush" with "midrash" unless there is some good reason to keep them separate? Thanks!

Comment: @WAF, I think of Midrash as a medieval body of work and drush as a genre that's been in use from then to now. Do you see them differently?

Comment: @Isaac is there a "transfer to meta" button for comments?

Comment: @David I don't think so.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - I suppose so. It's just not clear to me what "drush" as a genre refers to. Maybe somebody can write a tag wiki for it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in the noble prize site: [Shai Agnon's banquet speech](http://nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/literature/laureates/1966/agnon-speech_he.html) (that's in Hebrew, and there's also a [translation to English](http://nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/literature/laureates/1966/agnon-speech.html))

Comment: I said a recording...

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice :( .... I'll leave my answer, though, just in case someone would like the written speech